# Cassandra sync process

Tags: cassandra

I have a new cassandra node joining an existing cluster. Current nodetool netstat shows file transfer status at 25%. My question is, do I have to wait for compaction as well or is the node joining process considered completed when file transfer reaches 100% ?

Comment: The new node will accept new writes for the token ranges acquired while existing data from the other nodes is being streamed to it. So once this process finishes it will start accepting the read request.  It may run a minor compaction of its own. But how this concerns you?

Comment: our concern is that we have to show a customer of ours that this node has joined cluster and read and write requests can be performed on this node. So, correct me if i am wrong but according to your answer, we don't have to wait for compaction and node can be considered joined or operational when data transfer finishes ?

Comment: Just to make sure we are correct please connect to new node when the data transfer finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Once newly added node showing status UN, it will accept read and write requests. compaction will run in background and there is no impact however you can stop compaction as well for some time.